# std::array<T,N> need to be fetched in another types

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have class which has a std::array as  member variable  like this:

```
class my_class{
std::array<point<float>,4> corners;
}
```

I need to pass these `corners` to many functions. Those functions accept `(point<T>* const)`. So, I simply pass `corners.data()`.  The Problem is when some function accept a special `type` of the `point` class. For example,  `(point<double>* const)`. How should I pass the corners to that function with the less possible performance overhead.

**Code:**

```
class my_class{
public:
std::array<point<float>,4> corners;
}
void first_method(point<float>* const input);
void second_method(point<float>* const input);

int main(){
    my_class foo;
    first_method(foo.corners.data()); // OK  
    second_method(foo.corners.data()); // Problem
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have just realized that the class has nothing to do with my problem we can reduce it to:

```
void first_method(point<float>* const input);
void second_method(point<float>* const input);

int main(){
    std::array<point<float>,4> corners;
    first_method(corners.data()); // OK  
    second_method(corners.data()); // Problem
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh! it is not array even .. thanks for notifying me

Comment: `point<float>` and `point<double>` are unrelated, you have to create some copy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Your array is of the wrong type, or the functions have a parameter of the wrong type.

Either fix the array type, or fix the functions, or make a second array.

Comment: about the array why it is wrong. I have 4 and exactly 4 points nothing more nothing less. What do you suggest instead of it ?

Comment: You have four `point<float>`s.  The other function wants four `point<double>`s.  They aren't the same.  You will have to convert.

Comment: @MartinBonner not an option. some function take point<double> others take it with float. others with int

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: Then those functions are fundamentally broken if you expect to use the same data source. Why do the functions take arrays of different type?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  they are from another library. They may accept more than 4 points. They may accept the suitable type for them. but the scenario I am using just uses 4 with float type.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: I don't know why you keep talking about the 4. It's largely irrelevant. The problem you have is that your arrays are (literally) arrays of different types of things. You can't give a sheep to a sheep seller and a cow seller and a horse seller and a goat seller.

Comment: Sorry I was editing it.. Ok got it so there is no way another than converting my array each time I want to send it.. Thanks

Comment: @HumamHelfawi _"the scenario I am using just uses 4 with float type"_ If that were true, you wouldn't be trying to wrestle with `double` and `int` types also.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: You don't have to convert it each time; you could keep cached copies alongside the original. Or, if the library accepts iterators, you could pass an iterator that performs the conversion on the fly.

Comment: mmmm Nice Idea about keeping more than one array, iterators are not an option it is not a standard library

Comment: you should measure the cost of float->double conversion for your application's usage via profiling before you pre-emptively assume it is worth addressing as a problem.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: Plenty of non standard libraries take iterators. In fact, any _good_ library takes iterators!

Comment: @PreetKukreti: The type mismatch is already a problem. Performance has little to do with it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit unfortunately, OpenCV 2.4.10 is not taking iterators

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: That is unfortunate indeed. OpenCV is an industry standard library, largely well-designed; are you _sure_ it's expecting you to pass the same data to all of these functions? That seems unlikely to me. (It's a shame you didn't name the library in your question the first place.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am really surprised too, I spent that last 30 min reading the documentation hoping to find that I was wrong. For now it seems yes it is expecting to pass the same data. However, I am also posting a question about this issue right now hopping someone knows better about this issue regarding OpenCV.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: I don't see how they could comment usefully without knowing which actual functions you're calling. As usual, a lack of clarity and context in the question has led to confusion and ambiguity!