# using OpenCV with std::Array

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

This question is related to this one  [std::array<T,N> need to be fetched in another types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435578/stdarrayt-n-need-to-be-fetched-in-another-types)

I have noticed that OpenCV methods that deal with sequence of points accept either `cv::InputArray` or `const*` of the point type. e.g. (`cv::Point* const`)
When you have your points in `std::array`, you may depend on the `const*` input of the OpenCV method and call `my_array.data()` in order to get a pointer of the type. However, you will have to deal with the `cv::Point` to `cv::Point2f` and vice-versa problem. Furthermore, it is not really the right way.

I thought that the solution could be found in `cv::InputArray` where I will find iterator-based solution or at least overloads for C++ standard containers. I read its documentation and I shocked that it takes either `std::vector` or `cv::Mat` and some other Gpu data types.

The question is : How to overcome this problem? Did I miss something? in other word: How to use OpenCV with the standard container in the best way?

**Example:**

```
std::array<cv::Point,4> my_points,my_points2;
//fill my_points,my_points2
cv::fillConvexPoly(img, my_points.data(), 4, cv::Scalar::all(255));//this works
auto homography_matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(my_points.data(), my_points2.data()); //This will not work
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example? The short answer will be: either use `Mat` or `std::vector`. For any other container you need to convert.

Comment: In your previous question the problem was nothing to do with std::array (not lowercase), it was that some functions want cv::Point<float>* and some want cv::Point<double>* - and the obvious question is why?

Comment: In your previous question the problem was nothing to do with std::array (note lowercase), it was that some functions wanted `point<float>*` and some want `point<double>*` - and the obvious question is why?

Comment: if it was accept begin and end, the two problems will be solved in the same time,.. because cv::point and cv::point2f have built-in conversion functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with OpenCV functions. Simply `fillConvexPoly` is expecting `Point`, while `getPerspectiveTransform` is expecting `Point2f`. So you should pass the correct data type to those functions.

It has also nothing to do with `array` instead of `vector`. A `vector<Point>` would not be good either, but you need a `vector<Point2f>`.

You can convert your `std::array<cv::Point, 4>` to a `vector<Point2f>` and then pass it to `getPerspectiveTransform`:

```
vector<Point2f> pts(my_points.begin(), my_points.end());
auto homography_matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(pts.data(), pts.data());
```

Comment: if OpenCV accept iterators instead of direct vector container, both problem should be solved. shouldn't it?

Comment: In general, you can't expect that a library fulfills any your requirements, but it's the other way around. You should commit to the library style. OpenCV is highly optimized and usually expects all it's data to be in a given format exactly for this. If any OpenCV function would iterate over the container and convert/copy the data to another format, it will be far too slow. Bottom line, give OpenCV data as it expects, you can always wrap OpenCV functions to accept iterators

Comment: I see, However, I still think that any C++ library should accept iterator by default. At least, to provide a wrapper that accept it.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense in this case. You want iterators to perform implicit data conversion, and that's not what iterators should be used for. If a function accepts `foo`, you should give it `foo`, not `bar`. It's up to you to convert `bar` to `foo`. And your last comment is true the other way around: _any C++ library should provide iterator-like access to its data structures_. OpenCV has support for iterators in order to use Mat with standard algorithms using MatIterator.

Comment: What about the part related to its functions? should not it accept iterators too? it provides iterator for its container(Mat) but does not accept iterators of std containers?

Comment: I'm speculating, since I'm not an OpenCV developer and don't know their reasons, but... the primary data structure in OpenCV is `Mat`. They are even so kind that allows you to use `std::vector` seamlessly via `Input/OutputArray`. Why do you want OpenCV to accept `std::list` with not contiguous data, or fixed size `std::array`?

Comment: You mean the right way of using OpenCV is to store any data you want to do any operation on is to use cv::Mat?

Comment: For the **right** way you should probably ask on answers.opencv, where developers will answer you. But I'm inclined to tell basically **yes**. Keep your data in `cv::Mat` (or `cv::Mat_<Tp>`) or `std::vector` and you'll save a lot of headaches :D

Comment: mmmm I should ask really, if the answer was "yes use Mat", I will figure out that I need to punished by rewriting my all codes or to pray that my boss does not use SO :D  @Miki thanks for your time.

Comment: Please link here the discussion on answers.opencv... Good luck :D